# Is there a way to reference the value of a variable in a comment (just like in {} with f-strings)?

Tags: python, comments, f-string

Is there a way to reference (call) the value of a variable in a comment, just like in f-strings?

Kind of like the following:

```
S = 7

scenarios = [i+1 for i in range(S)] # Solve this problem for {S} scenarios
```

I know that this is how it works in f-strings, but not sure if it works in comments.

I would like to add this as I am not all too organized and this will keep me from forgetting to change it.

Comment: No you can't within python, maybe your **text editor** can handle this though. That said I find the "for {S} scenarios" more explicit as this defines the use of the variable

Comment: Why in world commented code would be executed? That not how comments work

Comment: Thanks for the answer @mozway, then I will just keep it like this.